# uploadify disable/hide the X(or cancel) once starts uploading

Tags: hide, uploadify

I am uploading the files once the upload button is clicked rather than upon selecting the files from Browse. I wanted to achieve 2 things:

1. Hide/Remove the Cancel button when I hit the upload button upon selecting the files
2. I see a small portion of color on the progress bar, that may be confusing to some users so I want to just fill that bar once the upload starts but until then it should be empty

```
$("#versionFile").uploadify({
    swf: 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
    uploader: 'UploadDocs.ashx',
    auto: false,
    buttonText: 'Browse',
    removeTimeout: 7
});
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for the fix for this for quite a time. And here what I found seems to be working..
In your upload control's jQuery(...init.js) file, you have to put some lines as following;

```js
//...some code
'onUploadProgress': function (file, bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, totalBytesUploaded, totalBytesTotal) {
//...some code
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
};

'onUploadError': function (file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
//...some code
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').show();
};

'onQueueComplete': function (queueData) {
//...some code
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').show();
};
```

That is it, you may send suggestions about it, if any.

Thanks for jQuery..
avigodse